# Task.WhenAny and Unobserved Exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, async-await

Let's say I have three tasks, `a`, `b`, and `c`. All three are guaranteed to throw an exception at a random time between 1 and 5 seconds. I then write the following code:

```
await Task.WhenAny(a, b, c);
```

This will ultimately throw an exception from whichever task faults first. Since there's no `try...catch` here, this exception will bubble up to some other place in my code.

What happens when the remaining two tasks throw an exception? Aren't these unobserved exceptions, which will cause the entire process to be killed? Does that mean that the only way to use `WhenAny` is inside of a `try...catch` block, and then somehow observe the remaining two tasks before continuing on?

**Follow-up:** I'd like the answer to apply both to .NET 4.5 *and* .NET 4.0 with the Async Targeting Pack (though clearly using `TaskEx.WhenAny` in that case).

Comment: Did you try running the code to see what would happen?

Comment: @Servy The finalizer doesn't throw, but I can't see a good reason why not.

Comment: I remember seeing @JonSkeet write somewhere that `Task.WaitAny` observes all exceptions on all arguments, but I can't find it now.

Comment: I think you meant `Task.WhenAny()`, `await Task.WaitAny()` wouldn't even compile.

Comment: @svick I did, thanks. I fixed this.

Comment: There is a false premise here: `Task.WhenAny` and `Task.WaitAny` will never throw exceptions.

Comment: @porges indeed, they yield a Task that will never throw.

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde @porges The calls will never throw, but the `await` will as it unpacks the exception delivered in the Task's failure result.

Comment: @DavidPfeffer I don't think so. Awaiting the task returned from `WhenAny` does not throw. It returns the task that caused the WhenAny to run to completion, and awaiting *that* task will throw.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> What happens when the remaining two tasks throw an exception?

Those `Task`s will complete in a faulted state.

> Aren't these unobserved exceptions, which will cause the entire process to be killed?

Not anymore.

In .NET 4.0, the `Task` destructor would pass its unobserved exception to [`TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception.aspx), which would terminate the process if unhandled.

In .NET 4.5, this [behavior was changed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/28/10217876.aspx). Now, unobserved exceptions get passed to `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`, but then they are ignored if unhandled.

Comment: On .NET 4.0 this doesn't terminate the process in the finalizer either though, and I don't know why.

Comment: If you installed .NET 4.5, you're running on .NET 4.5 even if you target .NET 4.0.

Comment: So the sample code really does fail on .NET 4.0? Any way to reproduce that behavior on my (4.5) dev computer?

Comment: I *believe* the Async Targeting Pack will actually add an `UnobservedTaskException` handler that prevents process termination (I have not tested this, but that was the behavior of the Async CTP for .NET 4.0), so anything using `WhenAny` will behave the same. There is [an app config setting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/28/10217876.aspx) to make .NET 4.5 emulate the old .NET 4.0 behavior.

Comment: So with NET45 do I have to check the task state explicitly after returning from WaitAny? That's pretty annoying.

Comment: And the [post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/09/28/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5/#comment-158265) you referred to doesn't seem to explain why `WhenAny` doesn't propagate the exception. That said I still feel `WhenAny`'s exception handling counter-intuitive - if `WhenAny` throws, it observes the exception. If it does not throw, the exception is not "observed". It feels in every sense that the design should be to throw the exception.

Comment: @KFL: My answer doesn't talk about `WhenAny` explicitly; rather, it answers the question of "what happens to unobserved task exceptions", which is what the op was actually asking (using `WhenAny` as an example). The result of `WhenAny` is just the first task that completes; you can observe that task (or any of the others) whenever you want.

Comment: @StephenCleary thanks for clarifying! The post you referred is a really good read! Actually I was here baffled by the fact that `WaitAny` doesn't propagate exception even if the first task faulted. And I'm struggling to find an alternative API that does throw in such case.

Comment: @KFL: `await Task.WaitAny(..)` gets you the first task to complete; to observe that task, you can use a second await: `await await Task.WhenAny(..)`

Comment: As of .NET 6 (year 2023), I found that `WhenAny` doesn't throw an inner exception, which means that the programmer should use IsFaulted/Exception properties on the task object to handle exceptions properly.

Comment: @robbiefan: `WhenAny` returns a task whose result is the task that completed first. To observe the inner exception, `await` the inner task. E.g., `await await Task.WhenAny(..)`

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the remaining task exceptions are unobserved. Pre .NET 4.5 you are obliged to observe them (not sure how the situation is on .NET 4.5, but it changed).

I usually write myself a helper method for fire-and-forget tasks like these:

```
    public static void IgnoreUnobservedExceptions(this Task task)
    {
        if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                var dummy = task.Exception;
            }
            return;
        }

        task.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                var dummy = t.Exception;
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted | TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
    }
```

You might want to include logging in production apps.

Comment: On .NET 4.0 this doesn't terminate the process in the finalizer either though, and I don't know why.