# WaitAll vs WaitAny

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I am little bit confuse for `WaitAll` and `WaitAny`. I am trying to get exception but when i do `WaitAll` it return exception but When use `WaitAny` returns nothing.And necessary is that if any of task complete work done.Is their any Replacement of `WaitAny()`. `WaitAll` and `WhenAll` are different becuase i dont want let all task done.   Like

```
try
{
    int i = 0;
    Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            i = 2 * 4;
        });

    Task<int> t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            int a = 0;
            int b = 100 / a;
            return 0;
        });

    Task[] tasks = new Task[] { t1, t2 };
    Task.WaitAny(tasks);
    //Task.WaitAll(tasks);// Working

}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
    var message = ae.InnerException.Message;
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: What's the confusion - you said you wanted to wait for *any* of the tasks to complete. It's highly likely (but not guaranteed) that `t1` will complete successfully before `t2` raises an exception, so you're told that `t1` completed successfully and you can carry on merrily with your normal flow.

Comment: Same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29681272/613130

Comment: I'd suggest using TAP and `Task.WhenAll` and `Task.WhenAny`, they are more modern and just "work better." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Situation like i have to use WaitAny so how got exception? Because I need if any one of task completed then boom work done.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that's not competely true, because even if both tasks will throw an exception - WaitAny will not throw. So WaitAny does not tell you that task compelted _successfully_, just that it completed (and perfectly possible that this means it failed).

Comment: Base example, easy to modify here: https://ideone.com/EebAcT, that shows that `Task.WaitAny` will stop waiting after an exception, but won't rethrow the exception.

Comment: You may find this interesting: [How can I await an array of tasks and stop waiting on first exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57313252/how-can-i-await-an-array-of-tasks-and-stop-waiting-on-first-exception)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this. Note, this uses the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public static Task<Task[]> WhenAllOrFirstException(params Task[] tasks)
{
    var countdownEvent = new CountdownEvent(tasks.Length);
    var completer = new TaskCompletionSource<Task[]>();

    Action<Task> onCompletion = completed =>
        {
            if (completed.IsFaulted && completed.Exception != null)
            {
                completer.TrySetException(completed.Exception.InnerExceptions);
            }

            if(countdownEvent.Signal() && !completer.Task.IsCompleted)
            {
                completer.TrySetResult(tasks);
            }
        };

    foreach(var task in tasks)
    {
        task.ContinueWith(onCompletion)
    }

    return completer.Task;
}
```

Comment: Nice. Better if make extension for this method.

Comment: @SAL but, what would you extend?

Comment: Note that OP uses `Task.WaitAny`, not `Task.WhenAny`.

Comment: @Evk, I'm aware of that, thats why I reference TAP in my opening paragraph. Its my assertion that everybody should use `Task.WhenAny` instead of `Task.WaitAny`.

Answer (score 4):

This is called [Unobserved Exception](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/09/28/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5/), which basically means that exception in newly created threads in [Task Parallel Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx) (TPL) ThreadPool, is not caught by the other thread or as stated in aforementioned link:

> While unobserved exceptions will still cause the
>   UnobservedTaskException event to be raised (not doing so would be a
>   breaking change), the process will not crash by default.  Rather, the
>   exception will end up getting eaten after the event is raised,
>   regardless of whether an event handler observes the exception.

This means that when using `WaitAny()`, if one of the tasks completes without any exception, exceptions in other tasks will not be caught.

Comment: I'll add that the `WaitAny()` will still "return" if one thread throws exception and the others are still "working".

Answer (score 0):

Your `WaitAny` implementation will throw error as well it depends what task will complete first. `WaitAny` does not wait till looser task (in most cases it would be `t2`) got completed - so it won't got exception from it.

**Update**

Indeed `WaitAny` will not return any error as descriobed here [Task.WhenAny and Unobserved Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678013/task-whenany-and-unobserved-exceptions)

Comment: If any case situation like this but i dont need to WaitAll() task to be completed. One Task got exception then how can  get exception? Does garbage collection threw?

Comment: WaitAny won't throw at all, regardless of which task completes first.